# How do I create a mobile navbar using bootstrap 4 with Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I am trying hard to successfully create a navbar with bootstrap 4 with vue.
Here is my code in App.vue:

NavBar

```
<b-navbar-nav>
  <b-nav-item href="#">Link</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item href="#" disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>

<!-- Right aligned nav items -->
<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

  <b-nav-form>
    <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
  </b-nav-form>

  <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-nav-item-dropdown>

  <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
    <!-- Using button-content slot -->
    <template slot="button-content">
      <em>User</em>
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Signout</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-nav-item-dropdown>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

The navbar comes out well on desktop but on mobile navbar-collapse doesn't work well. The NavBar brand is floated to the left
[image of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Hur.png)

Comment: I highly recommend reading [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote) @NickD

Comment: People should mark as duplicate or add an answer on why the post is irrelevant before downvoting. Otherwise, just a waste of time, my opinion, you can keep yours thank you

Comment: That is actually the correct behavior of the navbar based on Bootstrap-Vue docs

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the Bootstrap-Vue docs, it seems that the issue in there (and therefore on your code as well) is that the markup places the `b-navbar-toggle` before the `b-navbar-brand`, so when the size of the screen is reduced the button appears before the brand, causing the result you see. Simply move the `b-navbar-toggle` to be just before the opening tag of the collapse section and you will get the correct result.

```
<b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info">
  <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>

  <!-- Put the toggle here after the brand -->
  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

  <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">

    <b-navbar-nav>
      <b-nav-item href="#">Link</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item href="#" disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>

    <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
    <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

      <b-nav-form>
        <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
        <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
      </b-nav-form>

      <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>

      <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
        <!-- Using button-content slot -->
        <template slot="button-content">
          <em>User</em>
        </template>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">Signout</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    </b-navbar-nav>

  </b-collapse>


</b-navbar>
```